# How to read line by line with android using eclipse

Tags: java, android

I have been doing a project where I want to read a text file line by line. I have try to use the next line of code:

my text file name and location: `src/raw/cordenadas.txt`

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cordenadas);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (is, "UTF-8"));
```

But I receive the error unhandled exception `UnsupportedEncodingException` in the second line of code

Can some one please help me, and also what imports Java I have been mising? 
If you can help me by improving this line of code or by providing a new code it won't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encoding should be `"UTF8"`. See [Supported Encodings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try This::

```
String encoding = "utf8";
int SIZE = 8192;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), encoding),SIZE);
```